# Derived functor of additive functor

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories, derived-functors, derived-categories, additive-categories

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category which admits enough injectives and let $\mathscr{I}$ be the full subcategory of injective objects.

Let $F:\mathscr{C}\rightarrow\mathscr{C}'$ be an additive functor of abelian categories. In every textbook containing stuff about a derived category, we can find the theorem that states if $F$ is left exact, then it has a right derived functor.

One of the key points in the proof is that $K^{+}F:K^{+}(\mathscr{C})\rightarrow K^{+}(\mathscr{C}')$ sends acyclic complexes of injective objects to acyclic complexes (since the functor is additive and every short exact sequence of injective objects splits), and here is where the left exactness of $F$ is used.

Now the weird thing is that I have an easier argument in mind that does not use the left exactness condition, namely:

Let $F:\mathscr{C}\rightarrow\mathscr{C}'$ an additive functor. Then $\mathcal{F}:K^{+}(\mathscr{C})\rightarrow K^{+}(\mathscr{C}')$ sends acyclic complexes of injective objects to acyclic complexes.

Proof:

The acyclic complexes of injective objects are all homotopy equivalent to the zero complex and additive functors send the zero object to the zero object (since it send the identity on the zero object to the identity and zero morphisms to zero morphisms and the zero object in a  category is characterized by the fact that those two coincide), so the image of an acyclic complex is homotopy equivalent to zero in $K^{+}(\mathscr{C}')$ and hence acyclic.

Either this argument is wrong, or the whole mathematical community seems to stick to the particular assumption of left exactness for no reason whatsoever, but I am modestly assuming the first. Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: You can definitely derive functors that are not exact on either side. One reference that takes this explicitly into account is Enochs' and Jenda's *Relative homological algebra*. The setup there is more general in other directions too (in place of injectives/projectives, one uses so-called pre-enveloping/pre-covering classes for the given Abelian categories).

Comment: I haven't done an exhaustive search, but I just looked at a few books that contain introductions to derived categories, and *none* of them defined the right derived functor only for left exact functors.

Comment: Well thanks for your answers. @JeremyRickard in all of the references I have consulted the right derived functor is defined not only for left exact functors. However, my question was not aiming at the definition but at the particular theorem that I stated. Never mind, apart from what Pavel already recommended, I found references who do it in a general context (Weibel, and also SGA 4 1/2).